# how to joins two table in laravel

Tags: join, laravel-4, left-join, outer-join

I have the eloquent `Sub_items` which get the value of from the table `sub_items`

```
$sub_item= \Sub_items::all()->get();
```

This will give me the result:

```
[id] => 1
[item_id] => 1
[name] => tube light
[sort_nm] => tube
[deleted] => 0
[created_at] => 2014-02-22 12:24:39
[updated_at] => 2014-02-22 12:24:39
```

Here `[item_id]` is the another table `items` value .. that `items` table has fields like:

```
 id          int(10)        
 name        varchar(255)   
 details     varchar(255)   
 deleted     tinyint(1)
 created_at  timestamp  
 updated_at  timestamp
```

I get the value of id field of this `"items"` table in the result of the table `"sub_items"`

But i want to the value of the name field of the table `"item"` insted of `[item_id]`

How can I join this two table and get the individual column value?

Answer (score 0):

Use a [One To Many](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#one-to-many) relation using Eloquent and then you will be able to access *item* fields easily for each sub_item:

```
$sub_item->item->name
```